# Opengraph custom action asking to use only one object even when a single object is passed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I added a custom action "Add" with a custom object "Post" in the Facebook Developer console for my app. But, when I run the code in the Graph API explorer using the "Get Code" option in the console, I see a weird error.

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Only one of  reference objects can be specified for type devlotrop:add.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}`

The Graph API explorer is passing a single object of type Post, so I fail to understand what is this error referring to.

Since the object passed is the one auto-generated by Facebook on the `samples.ogp.me` domain, there is no error with the object itself.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing this wrong, I had created object and action type, but had not created any story. I created one and now I have a different error. So, the advice is to create your actions and objects via creating stories.

Comment: Can you explain more? I'm having the same issue. What is a story, and do you create this in the Facebook developer tools?

Comment: Yes, when you go to the Opengraph section of your app, you can create a custom story. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/

Comment: This is not written in their doc anywhere. Here are the steps you should follow : goto stories section create a story using your action and object then, you will see manage sample data option below, click on that and create sample object and sample action over there. This will create a separate URL which will be your sample object for reference use this object. Goto types-> press get code and you will get correct code on doing submit at graph API explorer it will generate an ID, which signifies success. (It took me 2 days to figure this out, hope it helps you).